# Правильная разметка таблицы в которой отсутствуют ячейки

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка

[image: нужная таблица]

Получается сделать так, но две лишних ячейки в thead. Как сделать правильно?

```css
  table, td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  td {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Test table</th>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Заведите для используемых ячеек свой класс:

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="td" colspan="4">Test table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td" rowspan="2"></td>
      <td class="td" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td" colspan="2"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td"></td>
      <td class="td"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```